# bash script read text file line by line and compare

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file with format:

```
1292177423,20160206
1292177450,20160326
1292177503,20160204
1234263435,20160130
1234263464,20160219
1234263557,20160218
1234263564,20160321
1234263569,20160219
1292177912,20160314
abcde*****,yyyymmdd
```

=====

I want to compare `yyyymmdd` with `20160115`. If `> 20160115` I want to put this line to 2 new file ( 1 only have number abcde*****, and 1 have line the same old file  number,yyyymmdd)

Can I do with bash script or perl script because the size of these file very large ?? and how can do it with bash script ?? Thanks

Comment: This is kind of a yes or no question; so I'd say the answer to this is "Yes." Keep in mind Bash scripts can process a lot larger files than most people think.

Comment: The answer is `yes`. If you want help actually *doing* that then you should make an attempt and ask for help when (if) you get stuck.

Comment: Yes,,, actually i want to ask how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Rather than attempting to read the entire file into some form of storage within your script, simply `read` a line at a time and make the needed comparison with the *date* portion in each line and then output the date (for redirection into a second file). For example, you could use something as simple, and flexible as a script that takes the *compare date* as its first argument, and then read from a filename given as the second argument (or from `stdin` by default). e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -z $1 ] && {  ## validate compare date term provided
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s cmpdate [file (stdin)]\n" \
    "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}

cmpdt="${1:-20160401}"      ## compare date (default 20160401)
fname="${2:-/dev/stdin}"    ## filename (default stdin)

while IFS=$',\n' read -r num dt; do     ## read num, dt from each line
    [ "$dt" -ge "$cmpdt" ] && echo "$dt"    ## compare date/output
done <"$fname"
```

**Example Use/Input/Output File**

Using your comparison date of `20160401`, and an input file stored in the `dat` directory as `ndate.csv`:

```
$ cat dat/ndate.csv
1292177423,20160206
1292177450,20160326
1292177503,20160204
1234263435,20160130
1234263464,20160219
1234263557,20160218
1234263564,20160321
1234263569,20160219
1292177912,20160314
1292177423,20160319
1292177450,20160326
1292177503,20160329
1234263435,20160401
1234263464,20160402
1234263557,20160405
1234263564,20160410
1234263569,20160418
1292177912,20160419
```

You could use the above script to check which date are greater than or equal to `20160401` and simply dump the matching dates to `stdout`:

```
$ bash cmpdates.sh 20160401 <dat/ndate.csv
20160401
20160402
20160405
20160410
20160418
20160419
```

When you are satisfied that all is working as desired, simply redirect the output to a new file, for example `dat/ndatenew.txt`

```
$ bash cmpdates.sh 20160401 <dat/ndate.csv >dat/ndatenew.txt

$ cat dat/ndatenew.txt
20160401
20160402
20160405
20160410
20160418
20160419
```

To output the data in your format `xxxxxyyyyy`, you can simply change the information you echo, e.g.:

```
while IFS=$',\n' read -r num dt; do     ## read num, dt from each line
    [ "$dt" -ge "$cmpdt" ] && echo "${num:0:5}${dt:0:4}"    ## compare date/output
done <"$fname"
```

Which would then result in:

```
$ bash cmpdates.sh 20160401 <dat/ndate.csv
123422016
123422016
123422016
123422016
123422016
129212016
```

Look it all over, and let me know if you have any questions, or if I misunderstood the information you wanted in file2.

Comment: Sr because make you understand wrong i mean xxxxxyyyyy is number ( and y is not year).. I just update.. The first script to catch the date/time greater than 20160401 is working fine. But the output for file2 is wrong :)

Comment: If I understand now, you want `[ "$dt" -ge "$cmpdt" ] && echo "$num"`. Give that a shot, it is the number before the date.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

file size doesn't matter.

```
awk -F, '$2>20160115{print $1 > "file1"; print > "file2"}' file
```

where file1 will only have the first field and file2 is the subset of records satisfying the condition